# How to remove characters from multiple files in python

Tags: python, batch-rename

I'm, trying to write a simple program to batch rename files in a folder.

file format:

```
11170_tcd001-20160824-094716.txt

11170_tcd001-20160824-094716.rst

11170_tcd001-20160824-094716.raw
```

I have 48 of the above with a different 14 digit character configuration after the first "-".

My final goal is to convert the above to:

```
11170_tcd001.txt

11170_tcd001.rst

11170_tcd001.raw
```

I know it's possible to os.rename files in python. However, I can't figure out how to batch rename multiple files with a different character configuration.

Is this possible?

some pseudocode below of what I would like to achieve.

```
import os

pathiter = (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(folder)
    for filename in filenames
)
for path in pathiter:
    newname =  path.replace('14 digits.txt', ' 0 digits.txt')
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path,newname)
```

Comment: So rather than pseudocode, what have you tried (in Python)?

Comment: Have you thought of using shutil.move() instead of os.rename()? If the files are consistently named, you just need the first 12 characters filename[:12] and the last 4, filename[-4:].

Comment: a text editor where you can modify entries vertically and a bunch of dos rename commands and you are there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a non-regex approach and considering your files all match that particular pattern you are expecting, what you can do first is get the extension of the file using `splitext`:

```
from os.path import splitext
file_name = '11170_tcd001-20160824-094716.txt'
extension = splitext(file_name)[1]
print(extension) # outputs: .txt
```

Then, with the extension in hand, split the file_name on the `-` and get the first item since you know that is the part that you want to keep:

```
new_filename = file_name.split('-')[0]
print(new_filename) # 11170_tcd001
```

Now, append the extension:

```
new_filename = new_filename + extension
print(new_filename) # 11170_tcd001.txt
```

Now you can proceed with the rename:

```
os.rename(file_name, new_filename)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use regular expressions for this?  Pavel's solution is much simpler, and explicitly looks for eight and six digits (however, see my comment on that answer).

Comment: @HuwWalters Simply providing an alternative solution. Nothing more than that. It is a fairly small piece of text where the regex solution is simple and to the point. But I just wanted to share a non-regex way to do it.

Comment: Excellent response. I made a for loop and integrated an "os.listdir" function and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @idjaw: Wasn't trying to shoot you down in flames there... but I tend to use regexes for most text-related problems, because they're both succinct and precise. (-:

Comment: @HuwWalters Didn't mean for my response to come off as me being annoyed. Typically, for small pieces of text like this I would probably write up a simple regex. But, since it was already posted, I decided to show the non-regex way. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try using regular expressions, like

```
import re

<...>

newfilename = re.sub(r'-\d{8}-\d{6}\b', '', oldfilename)

<...>
```

This will replace any 'hyphen, 8 digits, hyphen, 6 digits' not followed by letter, digit or underscore with empty string in your filename. Hope I got you right.

Comment: Better to use start/end of word delimiters `\b`, and you didn't remove the initial hyphen, but otherwise spot on: `newfilename = re.sub(r'-\d{8}-\d{6}\b', '', oldfilename)`

Comment: Agreed, it's better. Thanks. Edited the answer.